# How to I send a message from the WebView to React Native?

Tags: react-native

I’ve successfully managed to send a message from React Native (RN) to a WebView.

What I’m struggling with, is getting the message back from the WebView to RN. There’s no errors showing - it’s just that the message never gets through.

Here is the code which I’m using:

React Native code

```
 <WebView

        source={Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
        { uri: RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath + "/offlineplayer/index.html" } :
        { uri: 'file:///android_asset/offlineplayer/index.html' }
      }
          ref={(webView) => this.webView = webView}
          originWhitelist={["*"]}
         javaScriptEnabled={true}
         domStorageEnabled={true}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          useWebKit={true}
          //scrollEnabled={false}
          onLoad={() => this.sendPostMessage()}
          allowFileAccess={true}
          allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
          allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
          allowingReadAccessToURL={RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath}
          onMessage={this.onMessage}
         />

onMessage(event) {
  alert(event.nativeEvent.data);
}
```

WebView Code

window.postMessage("Post message from web", "*");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to communicate the web with react native is by using `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage` and the `onMessage` prop.
but `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage` only accepts one argument, which must be a string.

So change `window.postMessage` to `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage` to fix your issue.

For more information check this sample code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const html = `
      <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <script>
          setTimeout(function () {
            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("Hello!")
          }, 2000)
        </script>
      </body>
      </html>
    `;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WebView
          source={{ html }}
          onMessage={event => {
            alert(event.nativeEvent.data);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: thank you!! i tried but iam getting this error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage')

Comment: @jeevithaaiyappa could you share the full component.

Comment: could you please check this. https://safenote.co/r/5e906768f211b2@47207594

Comment: @jeevithaaiyappa that link also expired. I think it is better to update your code.